# Remove an array inside an array if one of the keys is null

Tags: php, arrays

i have 1 array with more arrays inside, and im trying to remove one of those arrays if they have a null key or its empty. Im doing this on PHP.

**What i have:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp] => 
            [fun] => 1
            [data] => 
            [data_d] => 
            [desc] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [emp] => teste
            [func] => 1
            [data] => 2021-08-30
            [data_d] => 2021-09-01
            [desc] => testetetetete
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [emp] => ersfewqef
            [func] => 2
            [data] => 2021-08-26
            [data_d] => 2021-08-28
            [desc] => dvgdgvqevgqe
        )
)
```

This means that the `[0]` will be removed because has one or more empty values. Is this possible? I have no clue on how to do this.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking at the values only? Your question states "a null key". Also, are you looking for null values only, or empty strings also? And what about numeric values of zero?

Comment: @AndrewHardiman empty keys or empty strings.

Comment: Empty strings AND null values? An empty string is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` for this (maybe not the cleanest)

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($v, $k) {
    #return true of false :: if true, then item is added in $result
    return empty($v['emp']) || empty($v['data']) ... ;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to filter elements of an array using a callback function.

If no callback is supplied, all empty entries of array will be removed. See `empty()` for how PHP defines empty in this case.

[PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: yes but if it has one valid string the ``[0]`` wont be removed

Comment: your goal is to remove only the element or the whole array?

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are on the right track with `array_filter`, but as far as how to identify which inner arrays have falsey values, you can just use `array_filter` again.

```
$result = array_filter($outer, fn($inner) => array_filter($inner) == $inner);
```

If an array is equal to its filtered value, then it does not contain any empty values, so using that comparison in your filter callback will remove all of the inner arrays with any empty values.

Just remember if you use this that any of the values listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) evaluate to false, so if you don't consider those "empty", you'll need to add a callback to the inner `array_filter` to make it more selective.

Comment: yes the others are on the right track but they wont remove the entire 'sub-array' it will only remove empty keys, strings. ill give a try to this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` and `array_intersect` to check for a number of needles in your haystack.

```
$newArray = array_filter($array, function($v) {
    if( empty(array_intersect($v, [null, ""])) && 
    empty(array_intersect(array_keys($v), [null, ""])) ) {
        return $v;
    }
});
```